# SVN: migrate-copy external folder into own project directory, keep and link history

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64, visualsvn-server

I have this svn structure:

```
project1 \ tags
         \ trunk \ ... \ libraries \ lib1
                                   \ lib2
         \ branch

project2 \ tags
         \ trunk \ .. \ external_folder = trunk(project1) \ .. \ libraries \ lib1
                                                                           \ lib2
         \ branch
```

Someday I have used in project1 some libraries like STM32 or FAT Filesystem. Instead of creating an own project called "external libs" and using SVN:externals, I let them stay and used them in an external folder via SVN:externals in project2. Now some time has passed and I want to "clean up" my repository.

Is there a way to migrate-copy this external folder into an "external libs" project while keeping the history?

The desired structure is shown below:

```
external_libs \ lib1 \ tags
                     \ trunk
                     \ branch

              \ lib2 \ tags
                     \ trunk
                     \ branch

project1 \ tags
         \ trunk \ ... \ libraries (extern) \ lib1
                                            \ lib2
         \ branch
```

Incidentally, I use Windows 7 as operating system and TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unrelated**

For `external_libs` repo I'll suggest to use inverted hierarchy

`/(trunk|branches|tags)/(lib1|lib2|...|libN)`

**Short answer**

Yes, keeping history of changes in `lib*` in new repository is possible

**Longer answer**

You can move data and all related revisions of `\ libraries\lib*` into new repository, but it will require to use tools outside of TortoiseSVN. Namely: you must to create dump of repository-part (`svnadmin dump ...| svndumpfilter ...` or just `svnrdump dump URL`) and loading this dump (`svnadmin load --ignore-uuid --parent-dir ...`) into new repository. After load you have to change **all** externals definition in `project1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try it out and mail back when it works! :)

Comment: As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613782/svn-dump-path-rename-via-windows-powershell-struggle-with-malformed-dumpfi
i used svn move. Thank you for your support + suggestung an inverted hierarchy!